How can I nest inline tasks?
I found inline tasks, which was a godsend, but finding out I can't nest org-headings inside of it, killed my high;)
Any other ways to get that?
I really want to work with inline tasks and then refile them, once I have a structured it the way I want. Inline tasks fit the job really well, when I had a plain text list;)

You cannot - inline tasks are headings at level 15 (by default) and cannot contain any higher-level headings. As for plain text lists, the commentary at the top of org-inlinetask.el says: ;; Note that you should not try to use inline tasks within plain list, ;; visibility cycling is known to be problematic when doing so., although it may be that the comment is obsolete; but I wouldn't know: I never felt the need to have an inline task.
